# PHP/MySQL PDF upload

Tags: php

I'm using the code below to add/edit pdf's yet it doesn't seem to be working at all. Any ideas/help greatly appreciated. S

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdfFile']['tmp_name'])) {
        $format = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['pdfFile']['name'],"."),1));            
        $str = strtolower(trim($_FILES['pdfFile']['name']));
        $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]/', '-', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/-+/', "-", $str);
        $pdfFileName=$str.'.'.$format;
        $pdfUploadFile=$pdfFileDir.$pdfFileName;
        $format!='pdf' ? $error='Invalid format uploaded for PDF File!<br />Please only upload files with the ".pdf" extension.' : NULL;
        if (!$error && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdfFile']['tmp_name'], $pdfUploadFile)){ 
            if($_POST['docFilename'] && file_exists($pdfFileDir.'/'.$_POST['docFilename'])) {unlink($pdfFileDir.'/'.$_POST['docFilename']);}
            $_POST['docFilename']=$pdfFileName;                
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(docFilename, assoc_cat, assoc_object) VALUES('".$_POST['docFilename']."', '".$_POST['categoryID']."', '".$_POST['id']."')"); 
        } else {
            file_exists($pdfUploadFile) ? unlink($pdfUploadFile) : NULL;
            !$error ? $error='The chosen PDF file failed to upload correctly.<br />Please try again, or attempt to upload an alternative PDF.' : NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Another "debug my code for me" question

Comment: If it doesn't work, in what way does it 'not work' ?

Comment: a little more info than "doesn't seem to be working" would help. In what way is it not working? Does it run at all? Does it throw any errors? etc etc etc?

Comment: Not a solution to the problem, but lines 8 and 15 of the given code are a horrible abuses of the ternary operator when a simple if() statement would have been much better.

Comment: Apologies, looks like i was missing the enctype="multipart/form-data" on the form post : (

Comment: You've got serious security holes in this. As well as the SQL injection, you're unlinking a file based on an unchecked filepath submitted by the user which may be subject to directory traversal.

Comment: Surely if it's in a password protected admin section it will be ok/safe from attacks?

Comment: @ss888 not necessarily. See [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSRF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to specify proper settings for:

- file_uploads
- upload_max_filesize
- memory_limit
- max_execution_time
- post_max_size

See:

- [How to optimize your PHP installation to handle large file uploads](http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php)

Also make sure that:

- You have specified the `enctype="multipart"` in the `form`
- Check the files array with `print_r($_FILES);`